# How to allow numbers with 2 decimal places only

Tags: javascript

The code allows me to enter numbers with decimals but I want to restrict the decimal so that user can enter only 2 decimals.

```
  numbersOnly(event): boolean {
    const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 46){
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: This is not an Angular question.

Comment: @cgTag, using this in my angular application so was not sure what other tag is suitable.

Comment: Angular uses reactive forms and validators. Any answers that improve upon your above code sample are not applicable to Angular validators. So I would change the tag to JavaScript.

Comment: I would agree with @cgTag. My answer really has nothing to do with angular.

Answer (score 1):

As cgTag stresses, this solution, and even the question itself, break the proper Angular form validation flow. This isn't proper Angular code, but a mix of normal JS into Angular.

Define a global variable (or a service if you want a pure angular solution), and fix your event handler to increase it:

```
var digits = 0;
var dotted = false;
numbersOnly(event): boolean {
    const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) {
        if (dotted) digits += 1;
        return digits <= 2;
    }
    if (charCode == 46){
      //We do not want to allow two dots
      return ! dotted;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You may also want to detect backspace - to catch removal of digits or the decimal point. Perhaps a [walkthrough](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp) on will be better for you in the long run.

Comment: backspace, delete key, copy and paste, highlight and type, etc.. etc.. there are many edge cases that also need to be handled.

Comment: @cgTag I think tutoring on proper Angular usage is out of scope, but I will add your comment as a warning at the beginning.

Comment: +1 for giving it a try. It is a very difficult thing to achieve. You'd have better luck finding a proper solution searching for a jQuery plugin that did numeric input validation then trying to write your own.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have the feeling OP will discover this soon enough.

Comment: kabanus, I highly appreciate the help in answering the question. However this did not help me resolve my issue and I did something else in my angular application to get it to work.

Comment: @Maddy No problem, good to hear. The proper recourse is to post your solution here, and accept it after 48 hours for a couple of rep points.

Comment: @kabanus, I will try to make a example of my solution so that I can post it here but there are so many components it is a little hard to do so.